# Basic implementation of Observable|Observer pattern

Tags: java, concurrency

My questions may sound silly. Yet it would be a great help if someone can help me to clarify it. Thank you.

My first question is:  Can I say that the following concurrent frameworks base on the same idea of Observable|Observer pattern ? (Running the execution then listening to the result)

- Guava listenablefuture
- ReactiveX observable
- Java future

My second question belongs to the part of awaiting for the result. Am I right or wrong if I make the following statement:

Although we have different ways to wait for the result in the above concurrent frameworks, all of them will need a mechanism which is conitnue checking for the result, which can be

```
while(result is not there){
  sleep for dd milliseconds
}
```

Then depending on how the framework is developed, thread, timeout check... functions will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question/statement: You (and I and Donald Trump) can say anything we like, the trick is to back up what we say with a convincing argument as to why it is correct. But more succinctly, I think your point is broadly correct.

To your second question: You are incorrect on this. First of all, Observable uses a callback pattern. And the simplest way to implement this is after the change that's being observed has been made, use that same thread to notify all of the registered Observables.

Also, locks and locking mechanisms are used a lot, particularly with threading. So when one thread calls thread.join() on another, that thread at least could/should keep a list of other threads that are waiting for it to complete, so once it has finished it can wake them all up. That way, busy/active checking for completion is not needed.